# cannot parse json with jq to store value in two vars

Tags: bash, select, jq

Team,
half way done but cannot figure out what am I missing. new to jq. searched google too.

json from curl response is below
`curl -u ${TOKEN}: $url | jq -r '.projectStatus'`

```
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "status": "OK",
      "metricKey": "new_reliability_rating",
      "comparator": "GT",
      "periodIndex": 1,
      "errorThreshold": "1",
      "actualValue": "1"
    },
    {
      "status": "OK",
      "metricKey": "new_security_rating",
      "comparator": "GT",
      "periodIndex": 1,
      "errorThreshold": "1",
      "actualValue": "1"
    },
    {
      "status": "OK",
      "metricKey": "new_maintainability_rating",
      "comparator": "GT",
      "periodIndex": 1,
      "errorThreshold": "1",
      "actualValue": "1"
    },
    {
      "status": "ERROR",
      "metricKey": "new_coverage",
      "comparator": "LT",
      "periodIndex": 1,
      "errorThreshold": "80",
      "actualValue": "59.42028985507246"
    },
    {
      "status": "ERROR",
      "metricKey": "new_duplicated_lines_density",
      "comparator": "GT",
      "periodIndex": 1,
      "errorThreshold": "3",
      "actualValue": "18.823529411764707"
    }
  ],
  "periods": [],
  "ignoredConditions": false
}
```

```
new_reliability_rating
new_security_rating
new_maintainability_rating
new_coverage
new_duplicated_lines_density
```

but I want to pull `actualValue` from these two sets and store them in var1 and var2

```
new_coverage
new_duplicated_lines_density
```

so I tried as first step below.

```
curl -u ${TOKEN}: $url | jq -r '.projectStatus'.conditions[] | map(select(.metricKey == "new_coverage"))
```

error

```
./curl.sh: syntax error near unexpected token `select'
```

I want to store the response in two vars.

```
var1 = "59.42028985507246" and var2 = "18.823529411764707"
```

Comment: You might try: `var1=$(jq '.conditions[] | select(.metricKey == "new_coverage").actualValue')` and `var2=$(jq '.conditions[] | select(.metricKey == "new_duplicated_lines_density").actualValue')`

Comment: Thanks but how are you calling curl?

Comment: You have `jq '.projectStatus'.conditions ...`, but it should be `jq '.projectStatus.conditions ...'`

Comment: If your `curl` call is returning the expected JSON, then your issue is not with `curl`.   As shown in the comments above and the answer by @knittl, your `jq` command was problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your single quotes wrong, they should enclose the full argument. Ther are some other minor issues with your jq program, e.g. `map` is not needed, when you stream/iterate the array.

Nevertheless, the following jq command should work:

```
json="$(curl ...)"
var1="$(printf '%s' "$json" | jq -r '.projectStatus.conditions[]|select(.metricKey=="new_coverage").actualValue')"
var2="$(printf '%s' "$json" | jq -r '.projectStatus.conditions[]|select(.metricKey=="new_duplicated_lines_density").actualValue')"
```

Alternatively, instead of storing the full json in a variable, you could store only the common part in the variable:

```
conditions="$(curl ... | jq '.projectStatus.conditions[]')"
var1="$(printf '%s' "$conditions" | jq -r 'select(.metricKey=="new_coverage").actualValue')"
var2="$(printf '%s' "$conditions" | jq -r 'select(.metricKey=="new_duplicated_lines_density").actualValue')"
```

To provide a fallback value, use parentheses and the [alternative operator `//`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Alternativeoperator://) in your jq program:

```
(.projectStatus.conditions[]|select(.metricKey=="new_coverageX").actualValue)//null
```

Comment: works perfectly: thanks a lot. I voted your alternate solution. I have an additional request if you can hint please. how would you handle negative case? like what if that  metricKey is missing. my expectation is var should be null.

Comment: @AhmFM I have updated my answer with an example how to use a fallback value